# jenkins multi-branch pipeline not triggering branch changes

Tags: git, jenkins

I have 3 branches on github. I set up a jenkins multi branch pipeline. I included only 2 branches out of my 3 branches on github in jenkins GUI. ON both of those 2 branches on github, I have a jenkinsfile in which I have a logic something like this.

```
if(env.branch_name == 'master'){
   build for production
}else if(env.branch_name == 'stage'){
   build for stage.
}
```

**The problem: when pushing new changes to master or stage branch, multi-branch pipeline doesn't start new build. it's like it has no idea that I pushed it or not.**

I have set up github webhook correctly. it works for single pipeline, but not for multibranch. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Old post I know. But try

```
if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'){
   build for production
}else if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'stage'){
   build for stage.
}
```

You can try a `switch(){...}` statement too.